# Getting nil using PDFDocument.init(NSURL: url) with a valid URL

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2, swift-playground

I'm trying to figure out why my code is getting nil when I test it in my playground.

I am trying to create an NSUrl where there is a PDF to load it into swift and get its text as a string.

When I first create the NSUrl my playground shows the pdf on the side quick view therefore I understand it is non null but when I pass this url to either the CGPDF or the PDFDocument methods I am getting nil.

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz

var str = "Hello, playground"

let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myfolder/Desktop/Desktop/Developer/test.pdf")
let julyPdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url)
```

Comment: In your path, `/Desktop/Desktop/` looks like a typo.

Comment: I know it looks strange but the thing is the folder on my desktop is actually called desktop that is why there is two desktops on it but the line with the path actually shows the pdf on the playground preview

Comment: Ok. I can't reproduce your error, though, your code works for me in a Playground if the file is at the right path.